# How AS3 class files.as work together with FLA file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I have two questions: Can i write app using just *.as files, and then compile them somehow in SWF? (i am making myself a webpage now)

Secondly, please look at the code, my problem is the same - I can't render text field onto stage, to be visible.

Flash say's 'undefined method addChild.' and 'Access of undefined property tekstuKaste through a reference with static type Class.'

This is a constructor type class inic which kinda serves for initialization, cos all i do is, I make an instance OF THIS class in FLA file by ActionScript, and expect, all application to work.

```
package {    
import pacinas.visuals.*;


    import pacinas.visuals.AE_kanva;

    public class inic {

        public function inic() {
            trace("===========");
            trace("inicializēt un izsaukt visu no Kanvas klases");
            trace("===========");
            trace(" ");
            var kanvas:AE_kanva = new AE_kanva();
            trace(" ");
            kanvas.varis();
            trace(" ");
            trace("===========");
            trace("inicializēt un izsaukt visu no Lauki klases");
            trace("===========");
            trace(" ");
            var laukiTxt:BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive = new BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive();
            trace("");
            laukiTxt.simpleText();
                addChild(BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive.tekstuKaste);
            }

    }

}
```

There is another EXTERNAL CLASS By whom i hoped to place a rectangles - that does not work too. Example:

```
package pacinas.visuals
{    
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class AE_kanva extends Sprite 
    {
        public function AE_kanva()
        {
        var kvad:Shape = new Shape();       
        kvad.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        kvad.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100,100);
        kvad.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(kvad);     
        trace("konstruktors - zīmē kanvu");
        }
        public function varis()
        {
            trace("te glabaas variaabljus");
            var ff:int = 4;
            var dd:int = 8;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is class i hoped will make text box for me (to fill it with XML later)

```
package pacinas.visuals

{
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive extends Sprite
    {
        public var tekstuKaste:TextField = new TextField();
        private var kontinents:String = new String ("XML SATURU CMON! a123");

        public function BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive():void
        {
            trace("teksta rāmis = konstruktora klase");
            addChild(tekstuKaste); <--CAN'T GET THIS TO WORK!!!
            tekstuKaste.text = kontinents;
        }
        public function simpleText()
        {
            trace("nekonstruktora f-cija no Teksta lauki");
        }
}}
```

p.s. I do not use document Class. Ok I will if it's needed. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I write app using just *.as files, and then compile them somehow into a SWF?

Yes - using the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) you can write pure ActionScript and compile it down into a working SWF. [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is a good IDE that takes advantage of this.

You will however need to understand how the document class works.

> Flash says `undefined method addChild.` and `Access of undefined property tekstuKaste through a reference with static type Class.`

In your code, this line is causing your issue:

```
addChild(BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive.tekstuKaste);
```

The first error `undefined method addChild` is because your class `inic` does not extend a class that implements the method `addChild()`. `DisplayObjectContainer` defines this method, so you'll want to extend that as a minimum, like this:

```
public class inic extends DisplayObjectContainer
```

The second error is because you're attempting to access a property of the class `BE_tekstaLaukiPrimitive` as if it were static. I suspect what you actually wanted to do was this:

```
addChild(laukiTxt); // laukiTxt is the instance you created.
```

Comment: Well , funny, i'm still fighting. Messing up my code from all sides. Thou not lucky this time .. human contact helps much more to finally get it. And finally wrap my head around basics.

Fellows, do not copy this code - the class ""inic"" has lower case letter in front, so it will not work anyways (thou trace statements did ..)

Comment: Thank you marty, the extends DisplayObjectContainer concept helped. When there will be logical basic rules explained semewhere in net?! Cos im getting frustrated of all thous "do as i do" tutorials - thay can't help if do not know how to build a statements together (just some pure rules please :) )

Comment: Well i still do not get it!
Is there a gold word in any body's head.

**This is most simple script: (single script assigned as document class to the empty FLA file)**

    package pacinas {
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.text.TextField;
    
     public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {
      var burti:TextField = new TextField();
      
      public function DocumentClass() {
       
       burti.text = ("misc");
       burti.x = 10;
       burti.y = 10;
       addChild(burti);
      }
    
     }
     
    }

 - `

> :'( why does it not add's child to stage?

`